# Is there any way to render text into image in pyglet?

Tags: python, pyglet

I used to use pygame to write games.I know I can render text to an image in pygame like this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
text = "Hello World"
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Microsoft YaHei', 64)
image = font.render(text, True, (104, 51, 207), (255, 255, 255))
pygame.image.save(image, "text.png")
```

But I haven't found a way to do the similar work in pyglet.

What I know is that I can use `pyglet.text.Label` class and `draw()` method to display some text, but it will always draw the label onto the window I created and I don't know how to inform which surface should it draw on.

This is the code I use to draw a label on a window:

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label("Hello World", "Microsoft Yahei", 64, anchor_x="center",
                          anchor_y="center", x=window.width // 2, y=window.height // 2)


@window.event
def on_draw(*args):
    window.clear()
    label.draw()


pyglet.app.run()
```

When I try to do this:

```
import pyglet

image = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((0, 0, 0, 0)).create_image(800, 600)
label = pyglet.text.Label("Hello World", "Microsoft Yahei", 64, anchor_x="center",
                          anchor_y="center", x=400, y=300)
label.draw()
image.save("test.png")
```

Only a transparent image is saved without any text.

Anyway, this is my first question in StackOverflow and I would be thankful for any help.

EDIT:I have found a solution [here](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/master/examples/text/advanced_font.py) for Windows users.I'll share it but I still want to find a cross-platform solution.

```
# ONE SOLUTION ON WINDOWS
import pyglet
pyglet.options["advanced_font_features"] = True

if pyglet.compat_platform != 'win32':
    raise NotImplementedError("This feature is only available on Windows.")


font = pyglet.font.load("Microsoft Yahei")
image = font.render_to_image("Hello World")
image.save("text.png")
```

Comment: why not use opencv to do it?

Comment: @finko Well, it is a solution,but it seems that it costs too much if I import both opencv and pyglet.Pyglet is a light-weight library,so if i use opencv,it may make my program much slower and bigger.Thank you anyway.

Comment: Depending on your use case, could you just take a screenshot of window and save it to a file? `pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save('screenshot.png')`

Comment: @Charlie Thanks.It is a very good idea.However,I just wonder if it is too slow to create a whole window.I'll try it soon and find if the image can be transparent.

Comment: What about a second window `window2 = pyglet.window.Window(visible=False)` to create it as an invisible window and try drawing labels there? Not sure if it will work. If you want a clear background on the window for saving purposes you may have to do `pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)` (after window creation) to make sure the background is cleared with transparency.